# Finding all unique combinations of overlapping items?

Tags: algorithm

If I have data that's in the form of a list of tuples:

```
[(uid, start_time, end_time)]
```

I'd like to find all unique combinations of uids that overlap in time.  Eg, if I had a list like the following:

```
[(0, 1,   2), 
 (1, 1.1, 3), 
 (2, 1.5, 2.5), 
 (3, 2.5, 4), 
 (4, 4,   5)]
```

I'd like to get as output:

```
[(0,1,2), (1,3), (0,), (1,), (2,), (3,), (4,)]
```

Is there a faster algorithm for this than the naive brute force?

Comment: disregard my comment. I thought you were trying to find all pairs, not all combinations. Still, you can apply the same idea of the sweep-line algorithm: sort all times and traverse them keeping a set of all currently covered intervals (uids). Every time you reach a new point, you remove all the intervals which are no covered anymore and build all the combinations of the current set + the current time's uid. Then add that uid to the set and continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, sort your tuples by start time. Keep a heap of active tuples, which has the one with the earliest end time on top.

Then, you move through your sorted list and add tuples to the active set. Doing so, you also check if you need to remove tuples. If so, you can report an interval. In order to avoid duplicate reports, report new intervals only if there has been a new tuple added to the active set since the last report.

Here is some pseudo-code that visualizes the idea:

```
sort(tuples)
activeTuples := new Heap
bool newInsertAfterLastReport = false
for each tuple in tuples
    while activeTuples is not empty and activeTuples.top.endTime <= tuple.startTime
        //the first tuple from the active set has to be removed
        if newInsertAfterLastReport
            report activeTuples
            newInsertAfterLastReport = false
        activeTuples.pop()
    end while
    activeTuples.insert(tuple)
    newInsertAfterLastReport = true
next
if activeTuples has more than 1 entry
    report activeTuples
```

With your example data set you get:

```
data = [(0, 1, 2), (1, 1.1, 3), (2, 1.5, 2.5), (3, 2.5, 4), (4, 4, 5)]

tuple           activeTuples               newInsertAfterLastReport
---------------------------------------------------------------------
(0, 1, 2)       []                                       false
                [(0, 1, 2)]                              true
(1, 1.1, 3)     
                [(0, 1, 2), (1, 1.1, 3)] 
(2, 1.5, 2.5)  
                [(0, 1, 2), (2, 1.5, 2.5), (1, 1.1, 3)]
(3, 2.5, 4)     -> report (0, 1, 2)
                [(2, 1.5, 2.5), (1, 1.1, 3)]              false
                [(1, 1.1, 3)]                             
                [(1, 1.1, 3), (3, 2.5, 4)]                true
(4, 4, 5)       -> report (1, 3)                          false
                [(3, 2.5, 4)]
                []
                [(4, 4, 5)]
```

Actually, I would remove the `if activeTuples has more than 1 entry` part and always report at the end. This would result in an additional report of `(4)` because it is not included in any of the previous reports (whereas `(0) ... (3)` are).

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be done in O(n lg n + n o) time where o is the maximum  size of your output (o could be n in the worst case).
Build a 3-tuple for each start_time or end_time as follows: the first component is the start_time or end_time of an input tuple, the second component is the id of the input tuple, the third component is whether it's start_time or end_time. Now you have 2n 3-tuples. Sort them in ascending order of the first component.
Now start scanning the list of 3-tuples from the smallest to the largest. Each time a range starts, add its id to a balanced binary search tree (in O(lg o) time), and output the contents of the tree (in O(o)), and each time a range ends, remove its id from the tree (in O(lg o) time). 
You also need to take care of the corner cases, e.g., how to deal with equal start and end times either of the same range or of different ranges.